# Error: package exists in another module: com.company.feature.apimodule in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module

I created a small project in Intellij Idea to mimic what I am seeing trying to migrate a large legacy codebase to OPENJDK16.  Here is the directory structure:

```
$ tree 
/cygdrive/c/projects/play
 |--api
 |----api.iml
 |----src
 |------module-info.java (module com.company.feature.apimodule)
 |------com
 |--------company
 |----------feature
 |------------ApiRunnable.java
 |--home
 |----home.iml
 |----src
 |------module-info.java (module com.company.feature.homemodule)
 |------com
 |--------company
 |----------feature
 |------------Runnable1.java
 |--Modules
 |----.idea (Idea stuff in here)
 |----out
 |------production
 |--------api
 |--------home

module com.company.feature.apimodule
{
    exports com.company.feature;
}

package com.company.feature;
public interface ApiRunnable
{
    public void play(String[] strings);
}

module com.company.feature.homemodule
{
    requires com.company.feature.apimodule;       //Error Module not found
//    requires apimodule;                         //Error Module not found
//    requires com.company.feature.ApiRunnable;   //Error Module not found
}

package com.company.feature;
public class Runnable1 implements ApiRunnable
{
    @Override
    public void play(String[] strings)
    {
        int count = 1;
        for (String str : strings)
        {
            System.out.println("String " + count++ + " " + str);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable1 myRun = new Runnable1();
        myRun.play(args);
    }
}
```

Note the directory structure is identical in api and home.  This is intentional as my legacy codebase has this structure.  This small example seems to duplicate the problems I am having and I can't figure out if the structure is the problem.  It did compile and run fine using the unnamed-module.

Error #1 when doing a rebuild

```
C:\Projects\play\home\src\com\company\feature\Runnable1.java
java: package exists in another module: com.company.feature.apimodule
```

Does this mean that I can't have identical package trees in api and home?

Error #2

The homemodule cannot see the apimodule, I keep getting (Module not found) no matter what I put in the requires line.

Is this related to Error #1?  If not, how do I fix this without resorting to the unnamed module for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@foo You are correct. The real solution is to not allow duplicate package names in different modules. This is not good coding practice but hey, I inherited it and this solution forced me to clean it up.

I solved this problem by renaming 5 packages to unique names and updating hundreds of import statements. Though tedious, it was relatively brainless work.

Since the modules identify things inside their `src` directory, they don't know which package is being referred to, the one in `api.src` or `home.src`.

I should have come back and updated this question, so thanks again @foo for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved by putting the module-info.java in the right directory.  This is poorly documented and was found by trial and error.
The right directory is api:

```
module apimodule
{
    exports com.company.feature;
}
```

and home:

```
module homemodule
{
    requires apimodule;
}
```

It appears that once the module-info.java files are in place, the Runnable1.java doesn't need the import statements, since the imported package is the same as the local one.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an actual solution. If you move the module-info.java outside the compilation range (as you seem to have done), they stop having any effect.  Then, the fallback behaviour for source from before Jigsaw kicks in and that's why it works - at least that's what it seems to be here.